# Defining static two-dimensional array as private

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, static

I had a two-dimenensional vector as member variable, and initialized it by the constructor.
Now that I have to declare it as static, I get compiler errors for wrong syntax.

It's declared and defined as that:

```
 std::vector< std::vector<int> > knowledge( 1, std::vector<int>(1, 0) );
```

in the private part of the class.

I get the compiler errors on that line:

```
expected identifier before numeric constant
expected »,« or »...« before numeric constant
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You'll get help more quickly if you actually post the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html) then do this:

```
// 
// In Foo.h...
// 
#include <vector>

class Foo {
    // ...
private: 
    static std::vector< std::vector<int> > knowledge ;
} ;

// 
// In Foo.cpp...
//
std::vector< std::vector<int> > Foo::knowledge(1, std::vector<int>(1, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

For using static class member you have to define this member outside a class, so compiler will allocate it in memory.

After you define a corresponding variable outside a class, you can initialize and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Static class members need to be declared inside the class, but defined outside. Example

```
class C {
    static std::vector<std::vector<int>> knowledge;
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> C::knowledge( 1, std::vector<int>(1, 0) );
```